# Should I refactor code for unit testing in mvp android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-mvp

I made an mvp application in kotlin and in each function of my presenter I call a view method so should I refactor my code for unit-testing or i just let this like that?

For exemple i have a function that make a regex

```
private fun checkPassword(isRegister: Boolean, pass: String, confirmPass: String): Boolean {
    val regex = Regex("^(?=.{8,}\$)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])")
    if (isRegister) {
        if (pass != confirmPass) {
            loginView.showNotMatchingPassword() // display an alert on a inputtext
            return false
        }
        if (!pass.contains(regex)) {
            loginView.showInvalidPassword() // display an alert on a inputtext
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart your router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is fine as per the MVP Architecture, you need not refactor the code. Your code is also testable in unit testing.